# If $\sin A = \cfrac{3}{5}$ with $A$ in QII, find $\sec2A$.

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

If $\sin A = \cfrac{3}{5}$ with $A$ in QII, find $\sec2A$.

I'm getting $\sec2A=\cfrac{25}{7}$. Is that correct?

Comment: Ever heard of wolfram alpha?

Comment: @user125736 How about its sign?

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. See my answer below.

Comment: @Awesome How would you use it to solve such a problem?

Comment: Elementary, my dear. first type : sin(x)=3/5,x<pi,x>pi/2 . see the answer. then type : sec(2*ans) which you obtained earlier.

Comment: The tag ([tag:exercises-and-solutions]) is supposed to be used for questions asking about exercise books and problem books, not for any question concerning exercises, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/exercises-and-solutions/info).

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\sec2A&=\frac{1}{\cos2A}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-2\sin^2A}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-2\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-2\left(\frac{9}{25}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-\frac{18}{25}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\frac{7}{25}}\\
&=\frac{25}{7}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin A = \frac{3}{5} $, then $\cos A = \frac{4}{5} $. Therefore,

$$ \sec (2A) = \frac{1}{\cos(2A)} = \frac{1}{\cos^2 A - \sin^2 A} = \frac{1}{\frac{16}{25} - \frac{9}{25}} = \frac{1}{\frac{7}{25}} = \frac{25}{7}$$

Comment: This is incorrect since $A$ was said to be in the second quadrant, so the cosine is negative.

Comment: . . . If you just change $\cos A = 4/5$ to $|\cos A|=4/5$ then you're OK.  You still get $\cos^2 A = 16/25$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I agree with you Sir. It should be $\cos A=-\cfrac{4}{5}$.

Comment: Sorry Mr. Lemur, I didn't mean to point out your mistake. I think you should edit your answer before getting vote down. (ô‿ô)